# How to generate an ordered list of parent-child elements from multiple lists, WITH MULTIPLE ROOTS?

Tags: perl, list, parent-child

I recently asked a question here, and got some very elegant answers. Here it is:

Visit [How to generate an ordered list of parent-child elements from multiple lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320398/how-to-generate-an-ordered-list-of-parent-child-elements-from-multiple-lists)

I have a similar problem, in which there can be multiple roots, which means there are separate trees. Here is an example (in perl);

```
my @rules = (
  [ qw( A B C ) ],
  [ qw( B D E ) ],
  [ qw( C H G ) ],
  [ qw( G H   ) ],
  [ qw( Z C   ) ]
);
```

In the list of lists `@rules`, A is parent of B and C. Generally, the first element is the parent of rest of the elements in the list.

I would like to process this set of arrays, and generate a list which contains the correct order. Here, A and Z must come before the other elements (the order of A and Z is not important, since they are independent). Here are two example solutions:

```
(A,Z,B,C,D,E,F,G,H), or (Z,A,B,D,E,F,C,G,H)
```

**Important:** Look at array number 3; H comes before G, even though it's a child of G in the fourth array. So there is not particular order of children in each array, but in the final result (as shown over) must have any parent before it's child/ren.

[image: Here, A, and H are independent of each other, but use common nodes.]

Comment: One easy solution would be to find all nodes who occur only as the first element (which means they are not referenced by any other node), and assign them all a "fake" parent, like; (X root1 root2 ..)

Comment: The code to which you link finds all the roots. What's the problem? Where's your attempt?

Comment: @ikegami: I have already solved the problem described by the method in my first comment, and I will soon post it, need to make some changes. I am looking for what the world of some millions developer has in it's mind :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about this? It's pretty straight-forward, though.

```
my @rules = (
  [ qw( A B C ) ],
  [ qw( B D E F ) ],
  [ qw( C H G ) ],
  [ qw( G H   ) ],
  [ qw( Z C   ) ]
);

my %weight_for;
for (@rules) {
  my ($parent, @children) = @{$_};
  $weight_for{$_}++ for ($parent, @children);
  $weight_for{$_} += $weight_for{$parent} 
    for @children; 
}

print "$_ = $weight_for{$_}\n" 
  for sort { $weight_for{$a} <=> $weight_for{$b} } keys %weight_for;
```

Comment: Fantastic and simple solution. Would you mind writing a small description of the strategy, more in terms of concept than this specific soluion? Thanks for your time..

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the parent occurs after the last occurence of any of it's children.